# connection information wordpress - localhost install

Tags: wordpress

I've just installed XAMPP on Mac OSX and when trying to install a theme or plugin in WP admin, I'm getting this screen. I've never gotten this on my shared hosting account. how to get rid of it on localhost?

[image]

Comment: If the answers below didn't work, change **User** and **Group** from `httpd.conf`. Check this out for complete instructions: [wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12267/149290](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12267/149290)

Answer (score 34):

We can simply add the following code to our `wp-config.php` to let WordPress use a different filesystem method than FTP.

`define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );`

Setting `FS_METHOD` to `direct` will also allow you to update WordPress Core and install themes from the theme repository locally.

Answer (score 5):

There are two alternatives to this:

1. First one is as explained in the first answer can be achieved by adding `define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );` into your `wp-config.php` file
2. Second approach, simply download theme or plugin from https://wordpress.org explicitly.

   Next, extract the downloaded theme or plugin, then,

   Put extracted theme into `.../wp-content/themes/` directory or extracted plugin into `.../wp-content/plugins/`.

Answer (score 4):

This have troubled me for years to the extent that i have to switch to Windows.
The first answer work perfectly well.

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

just had it and it will work. Love Ubuntu